# Serve PDF file at url with variable

Tags: templating, assets, filesystem, pdf

Is it possible to serve a file in a Twig template? I need to get a file (asset) from a global setting, and serve it at a particular URL.

This code is close, but it seems that `source()` is the wrong method to get the file contents with.

```
{% header "Content-type: application/pdf" %}
{% header "Content-Disposition: inline" %}

{% set filePath = [craft.config.environmentVariables.assetPath, filesImages.deliveryCalendar[0].filename]|join('') %}

{{ source( filePath ) }}
```

The variable `filePath` contains the correct system path to the file (/var/www/site.com/html/assets/file.pdf), but `source()` is clearly for templates and not files.

How can the contents of a file be streamed out to the browser?

Comment: For those interested: Brad's answer is very valid but I couldn't get controller actions to work. Instead I added a Twig extension modelled very closely after [dbug()](https://github.com/lukeholder/craft-dbug/blob/master/dbug/extensions/DbugTwigExtension.php), then used the above template file with my custom extension `{{ dlfile(cal.pdfFile[0].id) }}` to dump the contents of the PDF. https://gist.github.com/emcniece/bcf3d902e5469613fb1c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to make a simple Craft [plugin](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction) that added a Twig [filter/function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation) that wrapped PHP's [file_get_contents](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to grab the file contents, but at that point, you might as well just make it a wrapper for [craft()->request->sendFile()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/HttpRequestService#sendFile-detail).

Comment: Thx for the keywords and direction!! https://gist.github.com/samhernandez/352901974c99207fa81e

Answer (score 2):

In March, I released a **Digital Download** plugin which makes this process extremely simple...

```html
<a href="{{ craft.digitalDownload.url(asset) }}">{{ asset.title }}</a>
```

View the [complete documentation](https://craftpl.us/plugins/digital-download) to read more about how it works.

Comment: Thanks for contributing to the community! I definitely spent more than $30 worth of time trying to figure this out :D